# findAll() returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to get the list of all my values in table `users` by using the method `findAll()`.

This is what I have tried:

**User.java**

```java
package ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    private String dob;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

**IUserDao.java**

```java
package ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.dao;

import ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface IUserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

**UserRepository.java**

*Generated code by Intellij:*

```java
package ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.repository;

import ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.dao.IUserDao;
import ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.entity.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public class UserRepository implements IUserDao {


    @Override
    public <S extends User> S save(S s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends User> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> iterable) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findById(Integer integer) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean existsById(Integer integer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<User> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<User> findAllById(Iterable<Integer> iterable) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long count() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer integer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends User> iterable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {

    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```java
package ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.controller;

import ch.concertopro.webshopanalyser.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class UserController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    @RequestMapping("user")
    public void getUser() {
        System.out.println(userRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

The output that I get is always `null`. Why?

Comment: `public Iterable<User> findAll() { return null; }` not sure what else you expect...

Comment: Well you overrode findAll() and changed the return type to null . That's all.

Comment: Why do you implement `IUserDao` yourself?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that method has been generated by Intellij. If I remove that method, I'll get the error *UserRepository is not abstract and does not override abstract method findAll()*.

Comment: Read Lino's comment again @Proseller.

Comment: @Lino not sure if I get you right but I have now deleted IUserDao and instead implemented `CrudRepository` in `UserRepository`, like: `public class UserRepository implements CrudRepository<User, Integer> {`

Comment: @Proseller Delete your `UserRepository`, rename your `IUserDao` to `UserRepository` (keep it an interface) and try again.

Comment: @Proseller spring *should* generate the repository `interface`s itself, you don't have to implement it yourself, so just delete your `UserRepository` class

Comment: @Lino you are right. I didn't know about that. Just deleted it and it works fine. Thanks for this info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep

```java
@Repository 
public interface IUserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Delete `UserRepository` class its implementation will be provided by spring-data-jpa.

to access:

```java
@Autowired
private IUserDao repo;

repo.findAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

private String dob;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
}
```

You have to change your User class like this.You need the describe your table name with @Table annotation